# libssl Dependencies

Tags: apt, dependencies

Alright, so I was messing around with libssl and I manged to mess up libssl pretty well. It looks like I installed a separate version of libssl 64 than I've for libssl32 and now I can't use `apt-get` at all.

Output of `sudo apt-get install -f`:

```
$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libssl1.0.0:i386
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libssl1.0.0:i386
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libssl1.0.0:i386
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,004 kB of archives.
After this operation, 23.6 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
E: Internal Error, No file name for libssl1.0.0
```

Output of `sudo apt-get upgrade`:

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  libssl1.0.0 : Breaks: libssl1.0.0:i386 (!= 1.0.1-4ubuntu5) but 1.0.0e-2ubuntu4.5 is installed
  libssl1.0.0:i386 : Breaks: libssl1.0.0 (!= 1.0.0e-2ubuntu4.5) but 1.0.1-4ubuntu5 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f
```

Output of `sudo dpkg --configure -a`:

```
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
dpkg: error processing libssl1.0.0 (--configure):
  libssl1.0.0:amd64 1.0.1-4ubuntu5 cannot be configured because libssl1.0.0:i386 is in a different version (1.0.0e-2ubuntu4.5)
dpkg: error processing libssl1.0.0:i386 (--configure):
  libssl1.0.0:i386 1.0.0e-2ubuntu4.5 cannot be configured because libssl1.0.0:amd64 is in a different version (1.0.1-4ubuntu5)
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of openssl:
  openssl depends on libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.1); however:
   Package libssl1.0.0 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing openssl (--configure):
  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libssl-dev:
  libssl-dev depends on libssl1.0.0 (= 1.0.1-4ubuntu5); however:
  Package libssl1.0.0 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libssl-dev (--configure):
  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
  libssl1.0.0
  libssl1.0.0:i386
  openssl
  libssl-dev
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: did u try `sudo apt-get autoremove`

Answer (score 1):

Go to software centre and search for `mintupdate` and remove it. I had to do this twice as the first time failed.

I then installed it again and the problem was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Environment: Ubuntu 12.04 server

In my case, after running `sudo apt-get remove libssl1.0.0:i386`, I was not able to reinstall it; dpkg complained about an error in the `postinst` script.

After some digging, I found that the following command was causing the problem:

```
/usr/share/update-notifier/notify-reboot-required
```

We temporarily added `return 0` at the beginning of that script and libssl installed successfully.